# Powershell DSC Cannot invoke the Invoke-DscResource cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure-service-fabric, dsc

I'm trying to use DSC to configure the nodes in my service fabric cluster virtual machine scale set. Doing some registry edits, to keep it small I only show one below. When I run the functions manually by themselves they work fine. When trying to nest them inside one function I get an error.

```
 configuration ServiceFabricNode {
     Node localhost
     {  
         SSLPerfectForwardSecrecyTLS12 ConfigureSSL {}          
         ServiceFabricAntivirusExclusions AntiVirusExclusions {}    
     }
 }

 configuration SSLPerfectForwardSecrecyTLS12 {
     Import-DscResource –ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
     Import-DscResource -ModuleName GraniResource

     # Disable Multi-Protocol Unified Hello
     Registry "DisableServerMultiProtocolUnifiedHello"
     {
         Key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol
         Unified Hello\Server"
         ValueName = "Enabled"
         ValueType = "Dword"
         ValueData = "0"
         Ensure = "Present"
         Force = $true
      } 
  }

 configuration ServiceFabricAntivirusExclusions {   
      Import-DscResource -ModuleName WindowsDefender

      [string[]]$exclusionPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service abric\","D:\SvcFab\";
      Invoke-DscResource -Name WindowsDefender -ModuleName WindowsDefender -Method Set -Property @{ IsSingleInstance = 'Yes'; ExclusionPath = $exclusionPath }

      [string[]]$exlusionProcess = "Fabric.exe","FabricHost.exe","FabricInstallerService.exe","FabricSetup.exe","FabricDeployer.exe","ImageBuilder.exe","FabricGateway.exe","FabricDCA.exe","FabricFAS.exe","FabricUOS.exe","FabricRM.exe","FileStoreService.exe";
      Invoke-DscResource -Name WindowsDefender -ModuleName WindowsDefender -Method Set -Property @{ IsSingleInstance = 'Yes'; ExclusionProcess = $exlusionProcess } 
 }

 ServiceFabricNode
```

Results into

```
Compilation errors occurred while processing configuration 'ServiceFabricNode'. Please review the errors reported in error stream and modify your configuration code 
appropriately.
At C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\PSDesiredStateConfiguration.psm1:3917 char:5
+     throw $ErrorRecord
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ServiceFabricNode:String) [], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToProcessConfiguration
```

With debug enabled it shows the real exception

```
Cannot invoke the Invoke-DscResource cmdlet. The Invoke-DscResource cmdlet is in progress and must return before Invoke-DscResource can be invoked. Use -Force option if 
that is available to cancel the current operation.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

I cannot find a -Force option and Google seems to filter out all errors for Invoke-DscResource or I'm the first one using it. Does anyone know a solution? Maybe I don't have to use Invoke-DscResource for the WindowsDefender module, but I don't see another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the following blog information http://nanalakshmanan.com/blog/Composite-Resources-Explained/

WindowsDefender is a Composite-Resource

```
configuration ServiceFabricAntivirusExclusions
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName WindowsDefender

    [string[]]$exclusionPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\","D:\SvcFab\";
    [string[]]$exlusionProcess = "Fabric.exe","FabricHost.exe","FabricInstallerService.exe","FabricSetup.exe","FabricDeployer.exe","ImageBuilder.exe","FabricGateway.exe","FabricDCA.exe","FabricFAS.exe","FabricUOS.exe","FabricRM.exe","FileStoreService.exe";

    WindowsDefender x
    { 
        IsSingleInstance = 'Yes';
        ExclusionPath = $exclusionPath;
        ExclusionProcess = $exlusionProcess;
    }
}
```